# What is the source of the story from the Battle of the Nile?

Tags: naval

Here is a creepy story from history. As I remember the story, after The Battle of the Nile 1 August 1798 or the Battle of Trafalger 21 October 1805 someone on a British ship saw a boy sitting on a cannon very still, and when touched, the boy fell to the deck dead, without any visible wounds.  The story was that the boy had somehow been killed by concussion from the British cannons being fired or maybe a French shell exploding nearby.  Believe it or not.

So I wonder if anyone remembers reading that story and can find a source for it.

Comment: I've not seen this tale in descriptions of either of those battles but you might find something by searching for "wind of shot" (or "wind of ball"). There are several anecdotes that mention men being killed without a visible wound where their deaths were attributed to near-misses with cannon balls.